# Center SVG chart width jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, positioning

i'm trying to center SVG chart. Currently it's html looks like this:

```
<div class="svgWrapper">
    <svg>Generated svg chart</svg>
</div>
```

I can't specify width and height for SVG, because it's in responsive design. I can't get SVG width or height with jQuery

```
$('svg').width();
```

returns width of wrapper div, but svg width is not equal to wrapper width.

```
<div class="svgWrapper">
   <div style="float: left;">
       <svg>...</svg>
   </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how to center that generated SVG chart verticaly and horizontaly in wrapper div with changing w/h of SVG and wrapper (wrapper height always stays the same)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `canvas` element inside a `div` and assign `display: table-cell;` and than use `vertical-align: middle;` as well as `text-align: center;` to align *vertically* as well as *horizontally*

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DwcxB/)

```
div {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}

canvas {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 4px solid #f00;
}
```

---

Don't want to use `display: table-cell;` ? Than you can also achieve this using CSS Positioning. Here, am assigning `position: relative;` to the container element, and than am making the child element `position: absolute;`, just make sure you use `margin: auto;` there as it's crucial.

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/DwcxB/1/)

```
div {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}

canvas {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 4px solid #f00;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

> Note: Am aware that the `height` and `width` of the `canvas` are
>   dynamic, but I am just using fixed for demonstration purposes.